# How to filter a picklist based on the selected value of some other picklist in salesforce

Tags: android, salesforce, soql, picklist

I am creating an android app in which i have  integrated the salesforce SDK, in the salesforce custom objects i have two picklist(category__c & sub_category__c) how can i filter sub_category_*c based on the selected value of category*_c in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Make onchange event for category__c picklist which will filter by criteria sub_category__c.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!category__c}" >
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="subCat">
</apex:inputField>
<apex:selectList value="sub_category__c" id="subCat">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!filteredSubCategories}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Where on controller

```
 public void getFilteredSubCategories(){
      public List<SelectOption>  result = new List<SelectOption>();
      for(SelectOption so : allSubCategories){ // dont forget to init allSubCategories in constructor
          if(someCriteriaMet) { // add logic
              result.add(so)    
          }
      }
      return result;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i do this by using SOQL query

Comment: SOQL query has nothing to do with picklist values

Comment: Let me explain what i have done till now, as i am retrieving metadata of product__c object which contains picklist(category__c & sub_category__c) in the form of JSON format. So how can i filter it out in JSON  check the picklist values on the given link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLMLMNS1XQmRERScTNkSklRSUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could explain in the context of android. Thanks